# python dependencies of a specific package in the script

Tags: python

I have 3 libraries developed with Python. let's say a, b & c.

- a - my main module. which used `b`
- b - The module which uses `c`
- c - The module I am concerned about.

I am concerned about the library `c` about which of its methods have been used in `a`

The problem is that `a` directly does not import `c` anywhere. `a` only imports `b` which is developed on top of `c`.

How can I get list of `c` methods used ultimately used in `a`.?

Something like following..

```
>>> python specific_dep_finder.py <from_module> <concerned_modele>
ex:
>>>python specific_dep_finder.py /a /c

/a/one_feature.py
 - c.two.SOMECLASS
 - c.three.find_four

/a/two_feature.py
 - c.two.ANOTHERCLASS
 - c.five.CONSTANT
```

I am looking for a library if it is already developed or an approach on how can I achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just import the c module in the a (main module)? If the b module is the one that uses the c module most of the time, implement all the logic inside the b module and just use the b module as some kind of a middleware. If sometimes you need to use some methods from module c, without accessing them trough module b, just import the module c in the module a.

Comment: @JosipKolarić, I am currently not developing the whole structure. I have a testing task in the bucket and I want to only test the methods of `c` module if it was used in `a`.

Comment: I would say that only makes it easier then, if the c module has class containing all the methods, just instantiate the class and test the methods on that object. If the methods are static, just call the method from class without instantiating the class. If the c module has no class, just pure standalone functions, this makes it very easy to test. I don't know if you're using pytest, unittest or something else, but it all comes down to importing the c module inside the test and testing it's methods.

Comment: No, testing the whole `c` would take a large amount of time. And we currently have a limited time for testing. So we have scoped to test only the code of `c` which is being used by `a`.

Comment: Then test it the same way the logic is implemented, it doesn't make sense to do it other way. If you used the methods from `c` by importing the `b` (because the `b` is built on top of `c`) into `a`, then create a test which imports the `a` and `b` module, and test the methods from `c` by calling them from `b` module.